# cannot read all the lines from file in java

Tags: java, android

The file looks like this:

```
14.809034;56.876646;Vaxjo; 

15.809035;57.906646;Vaxjo2; 

16.809035;58.906646;Vaxjo3;
```

and the code is here so far:

```
InputStream in = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.cities);
if (in != null) {
    InputStreamReader input = new InputStreamReader(in);
    BufferedReader buffreader = new BufferedReader(input);
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(";");
    Scanner del = new Scanner(buffreader);
    del.useDelimiter(p);
     while(del.hasNextLine()) {
          while (del.hasNext()) {     
              city.add(new City(del.nextDouble(), del.nextDouble(), del.next()));     
          }
     }
     in.close();
} else {
}
```

And my output is just the first line 14.809034 56.876646 Vaxjo. What about the other lines?

Comment: You have not provided enough code - I don't see any printing. Also I have removed the catch clause, because it did not seem to match any try block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you also call `del.nextLine()` to proceed to the next line?

Comment: After reading a line, you'll want to proceed to the next line.

Comment: I dont get your point, can u write the code where i have to add

Comment: I think I handle that by using while del.hasnextline() is it ?

Comment: No, you don't. You only *test*, you don't *proceed*.

Comment: hey thanx it worked by just adding    del.nextLine(); after puting data in arraylist.

Comment: Seriously, have a look at the **Iterator pattern**, and understand the difference between `hasNext` and `next`. Same code pattern is being used by the scanner for tokens, and again for lines.